# display inline isn't working with paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to inline two lines on wordpress, tried to write same code on jsfiddle, and text is on two lines.

I can't add any style in paragraph tag because wordpress is adding paragraph tag behind the scene, without doing anything with paragraph tag how can I bring both lines in one line.

```html
<strong>
  <h2 style="display: inline;"> What You Will Learn Today</h2>
</strong>
<p>
  <a onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" style="display: inline;">Click To Expand</a>
</p>
```

Comment: You have control only over the `a` tag? or any other tags as well in the markup?

Comment: yes, everything else i can edit except <p>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the `strong` and then use the [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to make the `p` inline.

```css
.make-sibling-inline + p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<strong class="make-sibling-inline">
  <h2 style="display: inline;"> What You Will Learn Today</h2>
</strong>
<p>
  <a onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" style="display: inline;">Click To Expand</a>
</p>
```

Comment: can you please explain what is +p, will it effect everything on my website? or just this?

Comment: `+` selector is a sibling selector in css, it will affect only `p` tag that is AFTER a strong tag with `make-sibling-inline` class.

Comment: it will only change next first `<p>` element after  element with class `.make-sibling-inline` be careful if you have multiple element with `.make-sibling-inline`.  for more info: [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Comment: 16 years, first time I've seen `strong` wrapping a `h*` tag instead of being inside it. If only he swapped this around; this question wouldn't need to exist because it would've displayed in-line. This takes something very simple, and makes it more complicated then it needs to be, I also wouldn't recommend CSS that's so very specific.